# Batch delayed expansion not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, delayedvariableexpansion

Ok, I'm getting crazy and I don't know what else to do, I've tried several things and nothing is working.

Look at this sample code (test.cmd):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set VAR=before
if "%VAR%" == "before" (
    set VAR=after;
    if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
)
```

This is the generated output:

```
D:\>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]

D:\>test.cmd

D:\>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

D:\>set VAR=before

D:\>if "before" == "before" (
set VAR=after;
 if "before" == "after"
)

D:\>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

This is just a test, the code I need uses variables too and needs delayed expansion, but it this simple test doesn't work the other wont work either (I've tried, I ended up with a simple example to test if it worked).

EDIT: New code and output:

test.cmd:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set VAR=before
if "%VAR%" == "before" (
   set VAR=after;
   if "!VAR!" == "after" (
      echo It worked.
   ) else (
      echo It didn't work.
   )
)
```

Output:

```
D:\>test.cmd
It didn't work.

D:\>
```

Comment: Lose the semicolon in the line 

set VAR=after; 

and it should work

Comment: That's it! A semicolon... my, what a rookie I am :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to use `!var!` for delayed expansion. `%var%` is always expanded on parse stage.

I.e., change your code to

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set VAR=before
if "%VAR%" == "before" (
    set VAR=after
    if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
)
```

Comment: Nope, in that case the output is "if "!VAR!" == "after"".

Comment: Don't worry about the commands you're seeing echoed the screen; the point of delayed expansion is that it's done after that.  Put an @ECHO OFF at the top of your script and you'll see that it's working.

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of the cmd prompt, you must type “CMD /V” OR “CMD /V:ON”

After this testing code should work

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "_var=first"
Set "_var=second" & Echo %_var% !_var!
```

You should be able to see output “first second”
[image: sample cmd prompt screen]

Comment: `cmd /v` is superfluous, as `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` enable it, but `setlocal` only works in batch files. `cmd /v` is only necessary, if you want to use delayed expansion directly on the command line

Answer (score 1):

dont use == , in batch you must use EQU

For Example write:

```
if %bla% EQU %blub% echo same
```

Comment: This is nonsense, the only difference between `==` and `EQU` is the comparing of numbers. `IF 16 EQU 0x10` is true, but `IF 16 == 0x10` is false, as it compares always strings

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem.

```
set VAR=after;
```

delete `;` from the code above